# How do I run UITests on actual mobile devices in the App Center from a release pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, uitest, visual-studio-app-center-test

I want to create a release pipeline in Azure Devops to test my app.

I have 2 artifacts. One is an APK install file. The other is a UI test DLL.
My assumption is that I can upload these artifacts to the AppCenter in order to test the app.

But what kind of task should I create in my pipeline? and how should it be configured?
I cannot find a task related to AppCenter.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hi @jpc, is the answer below helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here

Answer (score 1):

We can use the task App Center Test. This task lets you run test suites against an application binary (.apk or .ipa file) using App Center Test, you can refer to this doc [Using Azure DevOps for UI Testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/vsts-plugin#general-configuration-steps) for more details

Comment: Thanks I found it ok and managed to run it - but with errors ie: "Error: Cannot find test-cloud.exe, which is required to prepare UI tests." ...

Comment: What helped me when i ran into this problem was adding the parameter "--uitest-tools-dir" to my existing command line arguments, and pointing it to the tools directory. Like this: --uitest-tools-dir  /Users/jeroenlamberts/Documents/GIT/MyApp/App/packages/Xamarin.UITest.3.0.7/tools/

Comment: Hi @jpc, Have you tried the Jeroen solution? As a workaround, you can set "$(build.sourcesdirectory)/packages/Xamarin.UITest.2.2.3/tools" on 'Test tools directory'. Please also check this [ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/6868)

Comment: I have actually abandoned using Release pipelines for the moment. And I am trying again using normal build pipelines. In a normal build pipeline I can access the test-cloud.exe. So thats no problem. But this ticket was about Release pipelines - which only use already created artifacts. I suppose I can save test-cloud.exe as an artifact in a build pipeline and then use it in a release pipeline... But as i said, I'm abandoning the idea of release pipelines for the moment